# will obfuscation make my program more optimized

Tags: algorithm, optimization, obfuscation

I am implementing a DES Encryption algorithm using C++, I benchmark it on a very large document(1.1MB) plaint text.

I have now reached about 1.1 sec on encryption, I need to squeeze off more performance out of it.

I was thinking of obfuscation, will that help in optimizing my code?

Comment: Obfuscating it won't make it more optimized. But optimizing it will probably make it more obfuscated. :)

Comment: @Anonymous downvoter: don't downvote a legal and clear question just because you don't like what the OP might have in mind - at least he is questioning his plan.

Comment: DES is too weak for nowadays - at least implement TripleDES or better AES.

Comment: Are you holding your 1.1Mb document on file?  If so, then your time is probably mostly down to disk IO rather than to the actual DES code.  Test it with a software generated file, say the same block repeated many times, to avoid any disk access.  @0x69's comment aboout DES is right.  Better to use AES.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think optimizing your code is the best way to optimize it:

- Fix redundant code
- Rethink the logic
- Remove unused or trivial variables
- Store commonly used values in variables to reduce redundant computation

Obfuscation makes code harder to read by:

- Replacing variable names with underscores or single letters *(compilers don't use variable names)*
- Removing whitespace to create a neutron star of unreadable text *(compilers do this internally)*
- Removing comments *(compilers don't read comments)*
- Sometimes adding useless code to further hinder readability *(making your program run slower)*

Comment: @Sherif: most modern C++ compilers have loop unrolling builtin into their optimizer. Perhaps you should switch to a another compiler?

Comment: @DocBrown, it's visual studio 2010 !! :D :D

Comment: I prefer GCC and Geany over Visual Studio, but I work with Linux. I wouldn't rely upon the compiler *completely* to optimize (but it does optimize quite a few things).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you did not write what kind of obfuscation you have in mind (on a source code level?), but generally: **no, it won't**. In a language like Javascript (or very old interpreted basic dialects), sometimes obfuscation and optimization go hand-in-hand (shorten variable names, deleting unnecessary whitespace/indentation etc.), but not in a compiled language like C++.

Of course, sometimes some kind of misguided optimization will lead to obfuscated code, but that is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

C++ compilers nowadays are really REALLY smart. Major optimizations come at a macroscopic level. Even Blender's example, removing unused variables, is not needed, since the optimizer will remove them anyway.

Obfuscation doesn't make your code smarter, it doesn't change algorithms, it doesn't introduce dynamic programming, or anything of the sort.

I don't see why you would want that though. With compiled languages, you don't have to ship the source code, you can, if needed, ship headers and libraries, but those don't give away implementation details.